# Running vert.x cluster backed by hazelcast cache in distributed mode

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast, vert.x

We are using Vert.X library to develop REST service layer to receive messages from many sources. Part of the requirements is to run REST verticle(s) in High availability (HA) mode. We are following vert.x core manual for implementation of VertX cluster to run in distributed cluster (3 nodes to start with).

Based on the documentation we did the following

1. Included hazelcast library in dependencies

   io.vertx
       vertx-hazelcast
       3.3.0
2. Created a fat jar with the following manifest entries and added resources folder in classpath which has required configurations to load. We took hazelcast-default.xml from vertx-examples from github

   log4j.properties
               config.json
               hazelcast-default.xml
           
       
       
       
           
               io.vertx.core.Launcher
               com.msg.verticles.RootVerticle
               resources/
3. Created a script file to trigger the launcher

   java -jar -Xmx2048m -Xms512m message-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -ha -D config=resources/config.json

Launcher fails to to pickup hazelcast-default.xml from resurce folder and stops with the following exception. Not sure what I am missing here.

$>java -jar -Xmx2048m -Xms512m message-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -ha -D config=resources/config.json

```
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:26 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand
INFO: Starting clustering...
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:27 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.RunCommand
INFO: No cluster-host specified so using address 127.0.0.1
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:28 PM io.vertx.spi.cluster.hazelcast.HazelcastClusterManager
WARNING: Cannot find cluster configuration on 'vertx.hazelcast.config' system property, on the classpath, or specified programmatically. Using default hazelcast configuration
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:28 PM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:28 PM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper
WARNING: Name of the hazelcast schema location incorrect using default
Jul 16, 2017 7:20:28 PM io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl
SEVERE: Failed to join cluster
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'null', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.hazelcast.util.ExceptionUtil.peel(ExceptionUtil.java:73)
```

Comment: @Rao - did you managed to solve above issue as I'm experiencing similar problem :(

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation of Hazelcast cluster manager](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/#_configuring_this_cluster_manager) you need to specify your Hazelcast configuration in a file named `cluster.xml` in your classpath (either embedded in the root of your fatjar or in a directory that is in your classpath).

Comment: Event then hazelcast library failed to parse xml

Comment: @NageswaraRao can you post your Hazelcast config xml to validate?

Comment: Seems, you forget to specify schema in your cluster.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.6.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.memcache.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.rest.enabled">false</property>

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by configuring zookeeper as co-ordination service. Which worked like a champ!!

https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-zookeeper